# Pybitcoinlib connecting to the Network

Tags: python, bitcoin

What I want to know is, if pybitcoinlib actually creates me a real bitcoin account.

```
w = Wallet.create(#NAME)
```

return:

```
1Pejuv73DtXUKn4VHWvqAy7o9tnpPtpGx7
```

Seems like it is creates me a real bitcoin account. However, I ran the upper code without network
But It is still making me new bitcoin account. How can this happen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remember that the Bitcoin network is a permissionless ledger. In practice, you don't need the network's permission to create a bitcoin wallet, you only need the network's permission if you want to spend bitcoin, which you get when you create a transaction that follows the network's rules, and submit it to the network.

When you create a bitcoin wallet, what you are doing is generating the public and private keys that will give you the right (on the Bitcoin network) to spend from that address, and this can be done offline. But, in order to check the balance of the address, or to broadcast a transaction, you will need to go online.

Comment: But that could lead overlap with original address and what I make . Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. So the protection against any theft, is that there are a cosmic number of possible bitcoin addresses, and it's near impossible to randomly generate the keys to a wallet that already exists. https://privacypros.io/btc-faq/how-many-btc-addresses